# Failed to get docker stats - Metricbeat and Docker

Tags: docker, elk, metricbeat

I am using `metricbeat` in conjunction with Docker to get metrics from a given container via hints autodiscovery.

I don't think its working properly as I am getting an error, in the error message key:

> failed to get docker stats: request returned Not Found for API route and version http://172.20.0.2:8101/v1.24/containers/json?limit=0, check if the server supports the requested API version

It appears to be targeting the correct container's IP address upon inspection of the json in `elasticsearch`.

Here is my metricbeat and demo app in docker compose:

```
metricbeat:
    container_name: metricbeat
    user: root
    image: mymetricbeat:docker
    volumes:
    # needed to access additional informations about containers
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
    - esnet
  myloggingapp:
    container_name: loggingapp
    image: loggingapp:latest
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8101
    labels:
      co.elastic.metrics/enabled: true
      co.elastic.metrics/module: docker
      co.elastic.metrics/metricsets: cpu
      co.elastic.metrics/hosts: '$${data.host}:8101'
      co.elastic.metrics/period: 1m
    networks:
    - esnet
```

Here is the yml:

```
metricbeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      hints.enabled: true                

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
  index: "sample2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

setup.template.name: "sample2"
setup.template.pattern: "sample2-*"
```

Also, for the event key, is the CPU statistic correct as it states `duration : 2090999` as I'm struggling to make sense of that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several volumes you need to map. 
See official setup docs:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/running-on-docker.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Comment: I added in all the other volume mounts that were stated in the docs and it still doesn't work.  Error: `failed to get docker stats: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://172.19.0.4:8101. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: I've just read in the docs (the part when monitoring the system) that paths such as `/proc` and `/sys` do not exist in Windows and Mac. I don't get why I need to mount these Linux directories?  In my previous `.yml` I accessed the `docker` module with `metricbeat.modules` and had `["unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]` as the hosts and it worked; albeit for every single container running on my machine.